# Move an object along waypoints in 2D

Tags: qt, path, pseudocode

I created this function to move a unit along way points that are saved in `list_`. Every Unit has its own `list_`. `move()` is initially called with the speed (distance/step) every step. Then depending on the distance to the next way point three possible actions are taken.

**Can you suggest any improvements?**

```
void Unit::move(qreal maxDistance)
{
 // Construct a line that goes from current position to next waypoint
 QLineF line = QLineF(pos(), list_.firstElement().toPointF());

 // Calculate the part of this line that can be "walked" during this step.
 qreal part = maxDistance / line.length();

 // This step's distance is exactly the distance to next waypoint.
 if (part == 1) {
  moveBy(line.dx(), line.dy());
  path_.removeFirst();
 }
 // This step's distance is bigger than the distance to the next waypoint.
 // So we can continue from next waypoint in this step.
 else if (part > 1)
 {
  moveBy(line.dx() , line.dy());
  path_.removeFirst();
  if (!path_.isEmpty())
  {
   move(maxDistance - line.length());
  }
 }
 // This step's distance is not enough to reach next waypoint.
 // Walk the appropriate part of the length.
 else /* part < 1 */
 {
  moveBy(line.dx() * part, line.dy() * part);
 }
}
```

Comment: If you are trying to animate objects, the new Animation Framework may be worth reading: http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/animation-overview.html

Answer (score 1):

I'll hate myself for suggesting a deprecated way of doing things, but there's no reference to the replacing method :(

[`QGraphicsItemAnimation`](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qgraphicsitemanimation.html)

It has addStep and linear interpolation stuff as a convenience.

It seems Qt devs would like you to use [`QTimeLine`](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qtimeline.html#details) itself as a replacement.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use Qt Animation Framework, more precisely [QPropertyAnimation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qpropertyanimation.html):

```
// I use QPainterPath to calculate the % of whole route at each waypoint. 
QVector<qreal> lengths;

QPainterPath path;
path.moveTo(list_.first());
lengths.append(0);

foreach (const QPointF &waypoint, list_.mid(1)) {
    path.lineTo(waypoint);
    lengths.append(path.length());
}

// KeyValues is typedef for QVector< QPair<qreal, QVariant> >
KeyValues animationKeyValues; 
for (int i(0); i != lenghts.count(); ++i) {
    animationKeyValues.append(qMakePair(path.percentAtLength(lenghts.at(i)), list_.at(i)));
}

// I assume unit is a pointer to a QObject deriving Unit instance and that
// Unit has QPointF "position" property 
QPropertyAnimation unitAnimation(unit, "position");
unitAnimation.setKeyValues(animationKeyValues);
unitAnimation.setDuration(/* enter desired number here */);
unitAnimation.start();
```

I haven't tested this solution, but you should get the general idea.

Comment: I also need to process the position of the unit for collision, damage and other things at each step and from time the path is modified. Does QPropertyAnimation give me access to this or does it simply execute the animation once it has been started. Also my units are subclasses of QGraphicsItem. I am not sure if QPropertyAnimation works with QGraphicsScene. What do you think?

Comment: QPropertyAnimation just changes the properties of QObject. If one of those properties represent position on QGraphicsScene, everything will work fine. I'd recommend to use QGraphicsObject instead of QGraphicsItem for animated objects. The collision/damage part is a problem if you need to change the path of animated objects after collision. Otherwise, I think you can check all the stuff you want inside the slot connected to QPropertyAnimation::valueChanged() signal.